# Как генерировать код XAML из обычного класса?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Всем привет, из-за крайнего недостатка времени решил спросить тут а не рыть кучу доков по WPF (хотя в дальнейшем обязательно займусь этим).
Суть вопроса: с изолированного хранилища из нескольких файлов тянутся данные, нужно в приложении их отобразить, вот каркас для одного элемента:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListBoxItem>
        <Rectangle Height="150" Width="150"
                   Fill="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
    </ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem Grid.Column="1" >
        <StackPanel Margin="12,0,0,0">
            <TextBlock Text="Новое соединение" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                       Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="94.21.12.1" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                       Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="root" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                       Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneSubtleBrush}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Windows-1251" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                       Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneSubtleBrush}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ListBoxItem>
</Grid>
```

Элементов будет произвольное колл-во. Как отобразить эту разметку из класса?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Положите этот код в UserControl, инстанциируйте этот самый UserControl когда нужно.

---

Только ваш код какой-то странный: почему `ListBoxItem`'ы лежат не внутри `ListBox`'а?

Если вам надо отобразить множество однотипных элементов, заведите `ListBox`, передайте вашу последовательность данных как `ItemsSource`, определите `ItemTemplate` согласно вашему коду (только выкиньте ручное создание `ListBoxItem`'ов).

Comment: Спасибо @VladD, привык я просто к хорошему (когда из PHP можно генерировать любую HTML разметку), думал и в WPF так можно, ан нет =)